# GCS bucket update frequency ,how do I set it?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to use logstash to push messages to the GCS using the output plugin below. I am able to see the msgs in the bucket, however they appear every hour and not real time. Where can I change the frequency of the log send?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage.html

P.S: I tried to add this to my config file but of no use:
flush_interval_secs => 2

my config looks something like this:

```
input{
kafka {
    zk_connect => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    group_id => "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
    topic_id => "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"
    reset_beginning => true
    auto_offset_reset => "smallest"
    }
}
output
{
    google_cloud_storage {
       bucket => "aaaa/bbb"
       flush_interval_secs => 15
    }
    stdout
         {
              codec => rubydebug
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.1/plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage.html#plugins-outputs-google_cloud_storage-uploader_interval_secs):

> Uploader interval when uploading new files to GCS. Adjust time based on your time pattern (for example, for hourly files, this interval can be around one hour).

Default value is 60.

Example:

```
output {
   google_cloud_storage {
     bucket => "my_bucket"                                     (required)
     date_pattern => "%Y-%m-%dT%H:00"                          (optional)
     uploader_interval_secs => 60                              (optional)
   }
}
```

Additionally, you can also set the `date_pattern`, which is the time pattern for log file.

Comment: I tried setting the uploader_interval_secs but the bucket doesnt seem to refresh. Is there anything else that can override this?

Comment: @learner Could you try changing the date_pattern to `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M"`?